# "Installation of module node-red-dashboard failed:" error

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I'm new to Node-red and cloud.ibm.com.  I'm using the lite version of the service with an academic account.  In the manage palette side bar, I searched for node-red-dashboard, clicked install and waited for a while until I got the error "Installation of module node-red-dashboard failed:".  I also got three strings after the error ""------------------------------------------", "", and "------------------------------------------" (those characters appear as dashes).  Where should I start looking to fix this?  Thank you!

Comment: Please elaborate it

Comment: What other information would be helpful?  I'm also using the option where the ibm cloud hosts the git repository for my instance of node red.

Comment: The output from the Node-RED Application log (found on the IBM cloud application page) from the time of the failure would be most useful. The work around is probably to add dashboard-ui as a dependency in  the  `package.json` and restage the app.

Answer (score 0):

I just attempted to recreate and got an error with the installation when my CF application did not have enough memory. However, when I upped the memory in my application, it worked fine.

[image: installation success]

I recommend following this tutorial on IBM Developer which explains the recommended steps to install the `node-red-dashboard` in addition to adding extra nodes to your Node-RED palette. It also explains how to deploy the application with 256MB memory.

https://developer.ibm.com/components/node-red/tutorials/how-to-create-a-node-red-starter-application/